# A weird css issue regarding the button hover, click and border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Below is the jsddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/xuhang1128/cmkbu07s/2/
The main related code is below. I used React and React-boostrap to implement it.

```
.design2-statusMonitor {
    margin-top: 20px;
    .list-group-item {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: transparent;
       // border: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
        border-top: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
        width: auto;
        &.selected {
            background-color: #2f749a;
        }
    }

    .list-group-item:after {
        content: "";
        width: 9px;
        height: 9px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -6px;
        top: 43%;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: white;
        border-top: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
        border-right: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    .list-group-item.selected:after {
        content: "";
        width: 9px;
        height: 9px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -6px;
        top: 43%;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: #2f749a;
        border-top: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
        border-right: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }


    .list-group-item:hover {
        background-color: #c0d5e0;
        color: white;
    }
    .list-group-item:hover:after {
        background-color: #c0d5e0;
    }
}
```

You can see that when I click any of the bubble button, the triangle looks not normal like below.
[image]
When I left the mouse outside of the button and click any other place, the bubble button became normal?

Could anybody help me to fix it? thanks very much. I have dug into it and googled it a lot, no result.

Answer (score 1):

Remove outline from the button focus

```
button:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmkbu07s/3/

Comment: Thanks. But why this page does not work in IE, it seems that the error related to jsfiddle?

Comment: stakoverflow should work in ie,at least in newer versions, what version of ie are you using?

Comment: the css should work in ie11 so the problem is likely your js or jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

When we click on a button, it gets focused and an outline appears.

Just make that outline disappear or remove by adding

```
outline:none;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmkbu07s/4/

Comment: Thanks. How to disable the hover effect when the button was in clicked state. Currently  even it's clicked, but when you hover it, the color still changed.

Comment: clicked state means the button is active, just add code
  `.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected:hover {
  background-color: #2f749a;
}`